# wordpress - getting rid of /subdir/ in all my links, css styles off after changing Site Url

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, I have the wordpress files in a subdirectory, `mywp`, and originally the site's homepage was `example.com/mywp/`.  I wanted to get of that `/mywp/` in all the links, so I did the following:

1. Copied `/mywp/index.php` and `/mywp/.htaccess` FROM `/mywp/` and pasted TO my root folder
2. Updated root's `index.php`, changed `require('./mywp/wp-blog-header.php');` to `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` (removed the `/mywp/`)
3. Updated the Site Url in wp admin's Settings - General FROM `http://example.com/mywp` TO `http://example.com`

After step 3, I visited http://example.com, and, the styles were off in both the site and the admin.  I viewed source and all the css references were missing the `/mywp/` in their url's.

In case someone asks, contents of my .htaccess file, that now resides in both my root and `/mywp/` subdirectory are:

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 5

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mywp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Do I need to tweak another setting to get the styles right?  And, do I have to remember this step if I ever update WordPress version or apply a new theme?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Changing the Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)  There's four easy methods to change the Site URL manually. Any of these methods will work and perform much the same function.

Comment: I may be confused on the terminology.  In my database, there's a row for "siteurl" and one for "home".  Which one should be for what the users see in their browser, and which one is for where the actual wordpress .php files are located? Thanks!

Comment: see the another option is to replace all the old url with new one in database(ex. example.com/mywp/ to example.com/) i am using this try it will work

Answer (score 0):

I was changing the wrong record in the db!  I was updating siteurl to be example.com instead of home.

Fix:
 1. set `siteurl` in wp_options table to be `http://example.com/mywp`
 2. set `home` in wp_options table to be `http://example.com`
 3. still do the steps I have in the original description of this stackoverflow post